# Merge 'screen-recording' and 'screencast' tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

On my tag checks, I discovered we have two tags for the recording of screen contents: [screen-recording](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-recording) (x1) already having a tag wiki, and [screencast](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screencast) (x5) without a tag wiki.

**Suggestion:** Merge the two, and make the more-intuitive 'screen-recording' the master. This way the tag wiki is kept as well.

I'm just updating the tag wiki for [screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen), including all the related tags, so this tag will be the fall-back for all issues not covered separately -- and is the most intuitive to look up in the tag wiki for existing alternatives. If the other tag wikis get updated, they might include a hint to check here (`screen`) for those, so they just need to be maintained at one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merged these, but I decided to make [screencast](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screencast) the master instead because:

1. It has been used more often
2. It is a reasonably common/mainstream term (with a relevant [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast) and everything)
3. As Wikipedia alludes to, the term "screencast" is an analogue to the term "screenshot" (for which we also have a tag: [screenshots](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshots))

...but I'd be open to discussion regarding this if it seems illogical.

Comment: Fine with me. My idea was just to keep it synchronous with other tags we have: 'video-recording', 'voice-recording', 'call-recording'. Now, when looking for [tags containing "record"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*record*), 'screen-recording' is *not* turning up. May be a minor thing for most people; only that I use those "wildcard tag searches" quite frequently when cleaning up tags or looking for alternatives. Now it instead sits with 'podcast' and 'webcast', which IMHO are not "that" related :)

Comment: The `screencast` tag does show up in the tag auto-completion if you type in "recording", though. I actually wonder if synonyms are supposed to appear in tag searches (I would honestly expect that they would). Or it could be a caching thing...I need to experiment with the search a little.

Comment: I wonder why they get mixed in the "tags" list (with the tags having no numbers, i.e. empty tags), but **not showing up on tag wildcard search via URL. Neither do they show up when using the search box on the [tags page](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags).** Hard to look for "similar tags" this way, if they might be hidden as synonyms -- I'd rather have it the other way round (synonyms not listed on the tags page, but turning up on search/wildcard-url).

Comment: I'm seeing really weird and inconsistent results. Searching for "system-" brings up the `system-clock` tag, for example (which is a synonym of `clock`), but searching for "clock" only shows the master tag. I would have thought that synonyms would be included in searches from the tags page. It seems like the actual tag entry field is the only place that synonyms get searched the way I thought they did.

Comment: Should we file a bug for that (must be MSO, I guess? Never did such a thing). And until solved: switch tag and synonym around (optionally; I don't think it's *that* urgent). // I noticed that discrepancy for a while already, but never took the time to dig into...

Comment: I'm going to let it sit a little bit and then try it again, to make sure it's not a caching thing. If it's still weird (I really feel like searching for "recording" should show *either* `screen-recording` or the master, `screencast`) then I'll try to form up a feature-request/bug report for MSO.

Comment: @Izzy: I've [written up a post on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174044/150283) to see if this can be addressed somehow. The current implementation is, IMHO, broken.

Comment: upvoted and commented -- thanks!